# Map .pk domain to azure website

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service, nameservers

I have developed my website using wordpress which is hosted on windows azure websites I need to give it my custom domain name instead using Azure provided.

I know we can do it using CNAME , A records etc according to [this link](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/)

But my registered domain name is .PK(not .com) which I got registered using serversea and according to them , for .PK domains they do not have any option to use CNAME  or A record and the only option they have is to set **Name servers**.

So Can I create my own name server for my azure website? or what will the right way to do it?

Zauk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is really the case then you have to find appropriate [DNS Hosting provider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hosting_service), which will allow you to **host** your **domain** with them - providing Name Servers, where you will be able to manage/change A/CNAME/TXT etc. records.

One such provider is [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/domains/dns-hosting.aspx). Another probably is [EasyDNS](https://web.easydns.com/). Don't ask for more or for pros and cons and which one to use, because this will go out of the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: thanks astaykov, I am doing same thing now as this is the only option.